# 16進数文字列を10進数にする計算

Tags: arduino

ArduinoUNOでIDE1.8.7を使用しています。

表題の計算を以下のように行いました。

```
int Dtoi(String s,int idx){
　int sum = 0,x,sl;
　sl = s.length();
　for(int i = 0;i < sl;i++){
  　　if(s.charAt((idx + i)) > 55){
　　　x = s.charAt((idx + i)) - 55;
    　　}else{
      　　　x = s.charAt((idx + i)) - 48;
    　　}
    　　Serial.print(sum);
    　　Serial.println();
    　　sum += x * pow(16,(sl-(i+1)));
  　}
  　Serial.print(sum);
  　return sum;
}
```

メインで

```
int a;
a = Dtoi("111",0);
```

のように実行すると
結果が

```
0
255
271
272
```

`a = Dtoi("11",0);`だと結果が

```
0
15
16
```

`a = Dtoi("1",0);`だと結果が

```
0
1
```

と表示されます。

2桁以上だと-1されるようなのですがなぜでしょうか？

Comment: 本題とは無関係な指摘を一つ。`if(s.charAt((idx + i)) > 55)` としていますが、ここは `if(s.charAt((idx + i)) > 65)` としないと、例えば `Dtoi("89",0);` とした場合に不正な値が返る事になります。まぁ、入力文字列のチェック(`[0-9A-F]+` にマッチするかどうか)も必要かと思いますが…

Comment: [Arduino Forum: Problem with POW() function](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=40776.0)

Comment: 確かに。65ですね。ありがとうございます。pow関数に精度の問題があるんですね

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらく、pow関数の結果がビット落ちしてるんじゃないかと思われます
そこんところは、
sum=sum*16+x;
にしてみよう

Comment: ありがとうございます。16のべき乗を取り出した数字に掛けたいのでそれだと違う数値になりませんか？

Comment: idxを０限定にするとこれでうまくいくと思われます
idxを使いたいなら、その数値分、１６を掛けるとか、idx*4ビット分左シフトするとか

Comment: 上記の方法で関数の目的は達せられました。ありがとうございます。